# laravel Socialite - Facebook doesn't return user's firstname & lastname

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-socialite

I'm using laravel socilialite to create a facebook login.

Here's my provider redirect

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider = null)
{
    if (!config("services.$provider"))
        abort('404'); //just to handle providers that doesn't exist

    if($provider == "facebook"){
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')
            ->fields(['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday'])
            ->scopes(['email', 'user_birthday'])->redirect();
    }

}
```

However, in my callback I dump my $user to see which data I receive

```
public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
{
    $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
    if ($authUser) {
        return $authUser;
    }

    switch ($provider) {
        case "facebook":
            var_dump($user);
            return User::create([
                'firstname' => $user->user['first_name'],
                'lastname' => $user->user['last_name'],
                'email' => $user->user['email'],
                'email_verified' => true,
                'provider' => $provider,
                'provider_id' => $user->user['id']
            ]);
            break;

        case "google":
            return User::create([
                'firstname' => $user['name']['givenName'],
                'lastname' => $user['name']['familyName'],
                'email' => $user['email'],
                'email_verified' => true,
                'provider' => $provider,
                'provider_id' => $user['id']
            ]);
            break;
    }
}
```

this is the data I'm receiving from facebook

```
object(Laravel\Socialite\Two\User)[215]
  public 'token' => string '******' (length=178)
  public 'refreshToken' => *****
  public 'expiresIn' => int ******
  public 'id' => string '*****' (length=15)
  public 'nickname' => null
  public 'name' => string '******' (length=15)
  public 'email' => string '*****' (length=24)
  public 'avatar' => string '******' (length=67)
  public 'user' => 
    array (size=6)
      'name' => string '*****' (length=15)
      'email' => string '*****' (length=24)
      'gender' => string '****' (length=4)
      'verified' => boolean ****
      'link' => string '*****' (length=60)
      'id' => string '****' (length=15)
  public 'avatar_original' => string '****' (length=66)
  public 'profileUrl' => string '*****' (length=60)
```

As you can I'm not receiving all the data I'm requesting, and I can't find out why.

How can I make sure facebook gives me the `first_name` and `last_name` of a user?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my working code:

```
    try
    {
        $socialUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields(['name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'])->user();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        \Log::error($e);
        return redirect()->route('register')->with('error', 'ERROR');
    }

    $user = new \StdClass;
    $user->id = $socialUser->id;
    $user->name = $socialUser->name;
    $user->email = $socialUser->email;
    $user->firstname = $socialUser->user['first_name'];
    $user->lastname = $socialUser->user['last_name'];
```

Try to remove `->scopes(['email', 'user_birthday'])` or replace it with my code.

Edit: I think i had the same problem and the `->user()` was the solution!